# What's the right way of uploading to FTP with retries with commons-net?

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons

I'm having issues dealing with a server which would close my FTP control connection in spite of me sending keep alive requests with ftpClient.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(CONTROL_CONNECTION_KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL_SECONDS);
Also sometimes it just dies out of SocketException and not the normal FTPConnectionClosedException. All in all, FTP is a very dodgy protocol I'm using a lot and each server I connect requires a bit of tweaking, however this one is giving a very hard time.

I know there's a million things I could be doing wrong, my question is, is there some solution with retries already implemented on FTP in case you lose the control connection, since is not something that should be shocking (proxies / firewalls sometimes just randomly lose your connection). Or is there some more elegant way of solving this problem.

I have something like this.

```
public void store(File fileToUpload) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String filename = fileToUpload.getName();
    int retries = 0;
    while (true) {
        try {
            ftpClient.storeFile(filename, inputStreamFactory.getInputStream(fileToUpload));
        } catch (FTPConnectionClosedException | SocketException exception) {
            LOGGER.debug("Control connection lost uploading {}, continuing.", filename);
        }

        // This sleep is because there's an anti-malware in the servers which makes the file not to appear
        // available immediately after an upload
        LOGGER.debug("Waiting {} milliseconds for anti-malware protection to process file", WAIT_AFTER_UPLOAD_MILLISECONDS);
        threadWrapper.sleep(WAIT_AFTER_UPLOAD_MILLISECONDS);
        if (!ftpClient.isConnected()) {
            connect();
        }

        LOGGER.debug("Checking if {} is already uploaded", filename);
        if (ftpFileChecker.isFileCompleted(listFiles(null), filename, fileToUpload.length())) {
            // Note this is likely to happen every time since their server will close the control
            // connection quite fast and FTPClient uses it at the end of storeFile
            LOGGER.debug("File {} was uploaded correctly", filename);
            break;
        } else {
            if (++retries > MAX_RETRIES) {
                throw new RemoteTimeoutException("Could not upload file, max retries exceeded");
            } else {
                LOGGER.info("File {} was not uploaded, retrying", filename);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void connect() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int retries = 0;
    while (true) {
        try {
            ftpClient = ftpClientFactory.createFtpClient();
            ftpClient.connect(server, FTP_PORT);
            if (!ftpClient.login(username, password)) {
                LOGGER.error("Login to FTP failed");
                throw new ConfigurationException("Login to FTP failed");
            }
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            ftpClient.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(CONTROL_CONNECTION_KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL_SECONDS);
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(uploadDir);
            break;
        } catch (FTPConnectionClosedException | SocketException exception) {
            if (++retries > MAX_RETRIES) {
                throw new RemoteTimeoutException("Could not upload file, max retries exceeded", exception);
            } else {
                LOGGER.info("Could not login, retrying");
            }
        }
        LOGGER.debug("Sleeping {} milliseconds before trying to reconnect", WAIT_BETWEEN_CONNECT_RETRIES_MILLISECONDS);
        threadWrapper.sleep(WAIT_BETWEEN_CONNECT_RETRIES_MILLISECONDS);
    }
}

public FTPFile[] listFiles(String directory) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int retries = 0;
    while (true) {
        try {
            return ftpClient.listFiles(directory);
        } catch (FTPConnectionClosedException exception) {
            LOGGER.debug("Control connection lost when listing files, continuing");
        } catch (SocketException exception) {
            LOGGER.debug("Socket exception when listing files, continuing");
        }
        if (!ftpClient.isConnected()) {
            connect();
        }
        if (++retries > MAX_RETRIES) {
            throw new RemoteTimeoutException("Could not list files, max retries exceeded");
        } else {
            LOGGER.info("Could not list files, retrying");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm getting SocketException Broken Pipe on listFiles, and I can't figure it out anymore since in my local server it works perfect, but in this particular one (hint it runs on Windows NT - :( - it runs some malware protection which prevents the files to appear on the server immediately and is apparently behind some very strange firewalls, and it drops idle connections after about 5 seconds, and they won't change the configuration cause they are a big company and claim it works for everyone else).

I tried VFS and investigated over other FTP clients but none I found seem to solve the problem, even more unhelpful, most of them (like ftp4j) are not in maven central which really puts me off trying them unless there's a guarantee it will solve my problems.

Any help is welcome.

Edit: Code given reflects the starting complexity of this, my current solution is more stable with quite a lot more complexity, but it's not elegant at all, so I leave the question open in case someone cares to contribute a nice solution.

Answer (score -1):

If using Spring, then consider Spring Retry. I believe the latest Maven version is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: if it were as simple as a retry wrapper I wouldn't have made a post for this, this project where this code was on already have retry utilities similar to what spring has released, it's not good for FTP though